# Can all vertex-transitive graphs be coloured and directed to make Cayley diagrams for groups?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Can all vertex-transitive graphs be coloured and directed to make Cayley diagrams for groups? By this, I mean valid groups that follow the group axioms. Certainly, all Cayley diagrams are vertex-transitive.

Here is an example:

[image: diagram]

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer is "no", but haven't the patience for the google-hole it will lead me down. You might be interested in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/14830/35478) though. I have only briefly skimmed the thread; it may contain an answer to your question (again, patience issues today :-) ).

Comment: (Also, its [Cayley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Cayley), with a capital C.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not the Petersen Graph for example.

Comment: Does this have something to do with it being one of the 5 vertex transitive graphs that lack Hamiltonian cycles?

Comment: Not exactly. There are only a handful of known vertex-transitive graphs without Hamilton cycles, but infinitely many that are not Cayley.

Comment: Great to know, also disappointing. It would make an excellent addition to your answer :)

Comment: It's fun to note that in this case "handful" is exactly five.